# Javascript: return selection(highlighted text) after DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This function returns text that the user has selected and wraps it in tags, in this case bold tags.

```
function makeBold() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("b");
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
}
```

Now after I call the function, the selection (highlighted text) is removed. How do I return that selection or maybe how do I call the function without losing my selection in the first place?

Comment: Works in chrome/Firefox. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Thrustmaster: I didn't say it doesn't work, it does but the text is longer selected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will work:

```
function makeBold() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount) {
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        var newNode = document.createElement("b");
        range.surroundContents(newNode);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

However, there are several issues to be aware of:

- Range's `surroundContents()` method will not work for every Range: it has to make sense within the DOM to surround the Range contents within a new node. For example, using `surroundContents()` on a Range that spans two paragraphs but doesn't fully select either will throw an error. See the [DOM Level 2 Range spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level-2-Range-Surrounding) for the formal definition of this.
- IE up to and including version 8 doesn't support DOM Range, and has a totally different `Selection` object to other browsers. IE 9 will have similar Range and Selection capabilities as other browsers.
- You need to check the selection's `rangeCount` property before proceeding, otherwise you'll get exception if there is no selection.

Comment: Wow! thank you for the function and for the remarks. This was very helpful.